# Using startsWith() method in switch case in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to use [`startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) in switch case in Java, but it expects a String and not a boolean value. I tried to create a wrapper function for it and return a String, but I am getting an error saying `constant expected`.

I want to convert the following if-else block in switch case:

```
if (currCmd.equals(allProduct)) {
    warehouseObj.viewItems();

} else if (currCmd.startsWith(buyProduct)) { // todo
    String productId = currCmd.substring(4);
    long lProductId=Long.parseLong(productId);
    cartProcessor.addItem(currUser.getUserid(),lProductId,currCart,warehouseObj);

} else if (currCmd.equals(viewCart)) {
    cartProcessor.viewItems(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);

} else if (currCmd.equals(checkout)) {
    cartProcessor.checkOut(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);

} else if (currCmd.startsWith(delete)) { // todo
    String productId = currCmd.substring(7);
    long lProductId =Long.parseLong(productId);
    warehouseObj.deleteItem(lProductId, currUser.getIsAdmin());

} else if (currCmd.equals(addProduct)) {
    if (!currUser.getIsAdmin()) {
        System.out.println("PERMISSION DENIED");

    } else {
        // remove sc
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        addProduct2Warehouse(warehouseObj, sc);
    }
} else  {
    System.out.println("INVALID COMMAND!");
}
```

Comment: You can't use a switch-case for that, end of story.

Comment: That is not possible until java 17. Switch/case does not allow those kind of statements. Java17 introduces [pattern matching](https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch-pattern-matching), which can most likely be used to squeeze this behaviour into that.

Comment: @f1sh Note that it's still a preview feature in Java 17 (so not yet a permanent language feature, and won't work unless you explicitly tell the compiler you want to use preview features).

Comment: @Jesper true, of course you are correct. That is just the only thing that came to my mind how this could be possible in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that currCmd is a String and using java 14/15 with preview or 16+ you can do it like this:

```
switch (currCmd) {
       case null -> System.out.println("INVALID COMMAND!");
       case "allProduct" -> warehouseObj.viewItems();
       case String s when s.startsWith("buyProduct") -> {
              String productId = currCmd.substring(4);
              long lProductId=Long.parseLong(productId);      
              cartProcessor.addItem(currUser.getUserid(),lProductId,currCart,warehouseObj);
            }
       case "viewCart" -> cartProcessor.viewItems(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);
       case "checkout" -> cartProcessor.checkOut(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);
       case String s when s.startsWith("delete") -> {
              String productId = currCmd.substring(7);
              long lProductId =Long.parseLong(productId);
              warehouseObj.deleteItem(lProductId, currUser.getIsAdmin());
            }
       case "addProduct" -> {
              if (!currUser.getIsAdmin()) {
                System.out.println("PERMISSION DENIED");

              } else {
                // remove sc
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                addProduct2Warehouse(warehouseObj, sc);
              }
            }
       default -> {
              System.out.println("INVALID COMMAND!");
       }
```

Using java 8 to 13 personally i would implement it as follows:

```
switch (currCmd) {
            case "allProduct": {
                warehouseObj.viewItems();
            }
            case "viewCart": {
                cartProcessor.viewItems(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);
            }
            case "checkout": {
                cartProcessor.checkOut(currUser.getUserid(),currCart);
            }
            case "addProduct": {
                if (!currUser.getIsAdmin()) {
                    System.out.println("PERMISSION DENIED");
                } else {
                    // remove sc
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    addProduct2Warehouse(warehouseObj, sc);
                }
            }
            default: {
                if (currCmd.startsWith(buyProduct)) { // todo
                    String productId = currCmd.substring(4);
                    long lProductId=Long.parseLong(productId);
                    cartProcessor.addItem(currUser.getUserid(),lProductId,currCart,warehouseObj);
                } else if (currCmd.startsWith(delete)) { // todo
                    String productId = currCmd.substring(7);
                    long lProductId =Long.parseLong(productId);
                    warehouseObj.deleteItem(lProductId, currUser.getIsAdmin());
                } else  {
                    System.out.println("INVALID COMMAND!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `currCmd` is a string which may look like `"buy $PRODUCT_ID"` or `"delete $PRODUCT_ID"` for the commands compared with `startsWith`, it may be worth to extract the "verb" from the command and use it in `switch` (using shorter arrow syntax of Java 12+):

```java
String cmd = currCmd.split(" ")[0];
switch (cmd) {
    case ALL_PRODUCT -> warehouseObj.viewItems();
    case BUY_PRODUCT -> {
        String productId = currCmd.substring(4);
        long lProductId = Long.parseLong(productId);
        cartProcessor.addItem(currUser.getUserid(), lProductId, currCart, warehouseObj);
    }
    case VIEW_CART -> cartProcessor.viewItems(currUser.getUserid(), currCart);
    case CHECKOUT -> cartProcessor.checkOut(currUser.getUserid(), currCart);
    case DELETE -> {
        String productId = currCmd.substring(7);
        long lProductId = Long.parseLong(productId);
        warehouseObj.deleteItem(lProductId, currUser.getIsAdmin());
    }
    case ADD_PRODUCT -> {
        if (!currUser.getIsAdmin()) {
            System.out.println("PERMISSION DENIED");
        } else {
            // remove sc
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            addProduct2Warehouse(warehouseObj, sc);
        }
    }
    default -> System.out.println("INVALID COMMAND!");
}
```